# li width resize from height?

Tags: css, resize, height, width, html-lists

I am making a site that has an inline-block list of one or more images.
The images should resize based on the containing div and should but side by side perfectly.
The images are sitting inside a list element which is inside a div.

The CSS for the images is simply height=100% & width=auto.

The images resize,
but the li elements they sit in do not.
This causes the images to get smaller but are no longer side by side because of the list element.
Is there anything CSS wise or any method out there to have list element's width resize based off the size of its content or have them resize based off their height?

Also would like to mention I really want to stray away from JQuery.

Code:

```
<div id="wrapper" vertical-align="center" class="row">
<ul>
    <li><img height="100%" width="auto" src='@routes.Assets.at("ribbon_left.png")' align="center" onClick='displayText(pin" + i + ")' /></li>
    <li>
@for(p <- pins){
    <div style="position:relative"><img height="100%" width="auto" src='@routes.Assets.at("ribbon_middle.png")' class="pinImage1" align="center" onClick='displayText(pin" + i + ")' /><img height="75%" width="auto" src='@p.image.value.largestImage.get.url' class="pinImage2" align="center" onClick='displayText(pin" + i + ")' /></div></li><li>
}
    <img height="100%" width="auto" src='@routes.Assets.at("ribbon_right.png")' align="center" onClick='displayText(pin" + i + ")' /></li>
</ul>
```

```
.row
{
  height: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul
{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

pinImage2
{
  left: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
}

pinImage1
{
  left: 0;
  position: inherit;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

example: first is maximized screen which works second is a smaller window and does not work. The reason they are separating like that is because the images are getting smaller but their li containers are not: 
[exactly what is happening](http://i.imgur.com/LNG8a.png)!

Comment: Please make an example of your issue on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Does the `div` container of `pinImage2` resize?